# ASP.NET MVC Core Razor wwwroot things not working/exists in app which is hosted on Nginx

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, model-view-controller, razor

I creted some views which are using (JS/CSS/png) files located in wwwroot. Everything works fine in local app hosting in specific local IP:PORT.
If the application is running through nginx then everyting works but I dont have access to any files from wwwroot directory... So the views are without any js scripts, styles etc.

This app have specific route prefixes like: `api/part/appName/Controller/ActionResultControllerMethod`

Current configuration for static files:

**Startup.cs:**

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
...
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
```

Njinx configuration for this app:

```
location /api/part/appName {
    proxy_pass http://pre_appName/api/part/appName;
}
upstream pre_appName {
    check interval=5000 rise=1 fall=3 timeout=15000;
    server MINE_HOSTED_APP_IP:MINE_HOSTED_PORT;
}
```

Have you any advices how to get access to this files in njinx hostings?

There is some screenshot from network DEV Tools:
[image]

There is screen from wwwroot files locations:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coupe hours - the answear is:

```
var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{

    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"{pathToContentRoot}/wwwroot")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/api/part/partName")
});
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.PathBase = "/api/part/partName";
    return next();
});
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "api/part/partName/{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
}
);
```